# Swift iOS - Resize parent view to contain rotated child view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

**Edit  -  How can I smoothly resize the red view to contain the rotated green view?**

I have an interesting view hierarchy for a map prototype I've built. It consists of a `UIView` which contains a `UIScrollView` which contains a `UIView` "holderView" which contains a `UIView` "rotationView" which finally contains an `ImageView`. HolderView is used for zooming and panning, rotationView is used for rotating. ImageView simply holds an image.

All functionality works as expected - panning, zooming, and rotating, though I've recently implemented rotating about a custom anchor point (the average of two touch points on the map). That works great, though the result rotates the rotationView outside of the parent (holderView).

I've researched and implemented various `resizeToFitSubview()` extension functions, though nothing seems to work. Has anyone ever experienced something like this and know of a good solution? On `UIGestureRecognizer.state == .End`, I'm trying to resize holderView to properly contain rotationView without using AutoLayout. Any suggestions/thoughts are welcomed!

Thank you!

- map image = ImageView
- green = rotationView
- red = holderView
- purple = UIScrollView

**Problematic scenario** - rotationView rotated and extends outside of holderView's bounds:

[image]

**Problematic scenario** - zoomed-out for further clarification. Purple is UIScrollView

[image]

Comment: So there's been some progress since posting, though not a coherent solution. To simply resize the holderView, I'm examining the distance between the rotationView's (minX,miny) and (maxX,maxY) points, and applying the distance to holderView's frame.width.

Comment: Does anyone have any thoughts? I think I'm stumped

Comment: Hey trying to keep this one alive. I've tried a variety of implementations including translating the holderView while expanding its frame. Unfortunately this is not working as expected either. Any additional insights or thoughts would be awesome, thanks!